# How to add a SQL Server role as a member of another role?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions, roles

I would like to roll-up permissions. Is it possible to add a role as a member of another role in a Microsoft SQL Server 2016 database? If so, then how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. simply by using sp_addrolemember, or the GUI as you'd normally add a user to a role:

```
ALTER ROLE 'BigRole' ADD MEMBER 'LittleRole'
```

Note that SQL Server will prevent you from making a role a member of itself, so if "BigRole" is already a member of "LittleRole", the above will fail.

Comment: A word of caution; sp_addrolemember is officially deprecated and the documentation recommends that you avoid it for new development. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Using a non-deprecated syntax: `ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [MyCustomRole]`